# NGXS spreading states in setState

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngxs

```
import { State, Action, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';

export class FeedAnimals {
  static readonly type = '[Zoo] FeedAnimals';
}

export interface ZooStateModel {
  feed: boolean;
}

@State<ZooStateModel>({
  name: 'zoo',
  defaults: {
    feed: false
  }
})
export class ZooState {
  @Action(FeedAnimals)
  feedAnimals(ctx: StateContext<ZooStateModel>) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.setState({
      ...state,
      feed: !state.feed
    });
  }
}
```

I am learning ngxs from gitbook, above block copied from there. 
In this exmaple `...state` assigned to object. why we need this? so we have only one object property feed and have already assigned `feed: !state.feed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ...state because you want to modify the state of the current state

Using spread operator you are making copy operation so the previous state will be copy to the new state object and you modify the data in the new created state object.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3]

const b = [...a, 4, 5, 6] =>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So this code

```
...state,
feed: !state.feed
```

You are making the new copy of the state object and modify the feed property inside your state object

Comment: ok I know but example state object only feed property, why ...state used?

Comment: I just explain to you you using ...state to copy current state object to new state objecy and modify on that new state